# Im trying out to install hive but it seems that I can't find any solution in the net for it

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, derby

Im trying to initialize the hive metastore using this command on cygwin

```
$ $HIVE_HOME/bin/schematool -dbType derby -initSchema
```

But it returned this error

```
WARNING: DEFAULT_LIBEXEC_DIR ignored. It has been replaced by HADOOP_DEFAULT_LIBEXEC_DIR.
Error: Could not find or load main class FAMILY
```

i've installed hadoop and derby correctly and its up and runnning already before I run this command

for reference im using this tutorial: https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-apache-hive-3-1-2-on-windows-10-70669ce79c79
and in my `/.bashrc file i inputed these

```
export HADOOP_HOME='/cygdrive/e/big-data/hadoop-3.3.0'
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export HIVE_HOME='/cygdrive/e/big-data/apache-hive-3.1.2'
export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$HIVE_HOME/lib/*.jar
```

I feel like the error is being caused by my pc username because it has a space on it *(I feel like I should have just used a vm instead)*, had a similar problem with installing hadoop but I dont know where to find the %USER_NAME% thing for hive

Comment: Personally, I'd use Docker Compose Hive metastore and mysql rather than embedded Derby

Comment: I am facing the exact problem. If you had solved it, can you please let me know. Thanks!